# htaccess complex setup for SSL proxy for images

Tags: apache, .htaccess, rules

I need a help to setup a complex .HTACCESS rule.

My site (abc.com) has SSL setup.
The gallery images are hosted in an external site pqr.com, it doesn't have SSL.

I want, if my site (abc.com) is opened in ssl (that is https://abc.com) the external images (jpeg or png) that are coming from pqr.com will use a SSL proxy.
Example - http://pqr.com/pic1.png will convert into https://abc.com/proxy/pqr.com/pic1.png

How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

To convert `http://pqr.com/pic1.png to https://abc.com/proxy/pqr.com/pic1.png` - you will need rules on external domain pqr.com and also need the same images on abc.com (which will not make any sense).

The other option is to install SSL on pqr.com and provide secure access. Check out this [article](https://www.sslshopper.com/article-do-i-need-an-ssl-certificate-for-my-website.html) and see if SSL installation is really needed for pqr.com.

Hope this helps!